# I fail to connect to Trino from Apache Superset

Tags: presto, apache-superset, trino

I’m setting up Trino and superset in my local docker desktop kubernetes on mac using the provided helm charts for each. For superset I added the pyhive, trino and sqlalchemy-trino pip packages as `additionalRequirements`.
When adding the database in superset with this connection string `trino://trino@trino:8080/iceberg` the connection test works, but I still can not *create* the database in superset.
There is a hint in the superset response to configure the advanced settings, but I could not make it work. Any help on what might be missing? This python script here works for me:

```py
import trino
conn = trino.dbapi.connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=8080,
    user='trino',
    catalog='iceberg',
    schema='lala',
)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM system.runtime.nodes')
rows = cur.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar issue when [creating tables in Superset for the Trino Community Broadcast](https://trino.io/episodes/12.html). By default Superset disables any DDL and DML to avoid accidents from the UI. Try opening the Database settings for Trino, selecting the SQL Lab Settings tab, and click, Allow DML. I know this is technically DDL but there were some extra commands that fell outside of DML that this enabled so it might work for you.

[image: Edit database / SQL lab settings used to allow DML in Superset]

Comment: In the meantime I got it working. I'm not sure what exactly fixed it, but I think my hive-metastore setup was broken. I'm using trino with iceberg and an external hive-metastore (standalone). It works now also without the DDL / DML settings enabled.

Comment: Oh bummer that you're not sure what changed. Glad you got it working though! If you have any further questions I recommend you join the Trino slack: https://trino.io/slack.html.